# How to use CSS :first-child pseudo-element

Tags: html, css

This is the css I am using to style my menu

```
.vd-menu-item { padding: 0; margin: 0; height: 100%; }
.vd-menu-item:before {content: " | ";}
.vd-menu-litem:first-child:before {content: " ";}
```

HTML

```
<div class="vd-menu vd-menu-horizontal">
    <ul>
        <li class="vd-menu-item"><a href="#" class="vd-menu-link">News</a></li>
        <li class="vd-menu-item"><a href="#" class="vd-menu-link">Sports</a></li>
        <li class="vd-menu-item"><a href="#" class="vd-menu-link">Finance</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to separate the menu list with "|" in between them like

```
News | Sports | Finance
```

So thought of using :before the li. It works good but the first child, in this case "News" has "|" before it.

```
| News | Sports | Finance
```

I tried using first-child but it does not work as expected. All the separator "|" disappears.

Can you help?

Comment: How about this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/693/?

Comment: If you don't need the space before the first child, consider the terser `.vd-menu-item + .vd-menu-item::before {content: " | ";}`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the :not Selector to make it easier.

```
.vd-menu-item { padding: 0; margin: 0; height: 100%; }
.vd-menu-item:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)::before {content: " | ";}
```

I hope i helped you out :)

Comment: tried your solution and this is what I get " News | Sports Finance " where as I am looking for " News | Sports | Finance "

Comment: Hmm, than i cant help out sorry :-(

Comment: wait, I did this ".vd-menu-item:not(:first-child)::before {content: " | ";}" and it works. Hopefully it's the right way of doing it. Your idea. Can you please edit your answer so that I accept

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a typo in your code: `.vd-menu-litem:`